# Cannot assign "u'1'": "PropiedadesCond.Condominio" must be a "Condominios" instance

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to assign the session-generated company id to a new product belonging to that company but I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what it refers to.

Any help will be much appreciated

Models.py

```
class Condominios(models.Model):
    idCondominio = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=15)
    idUser = models.OneToOneField(User)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Colonia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CP = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Municipio = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Pais = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Tamanom2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Frentem2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Fondom2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.Nombre)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/inicioc/")
def nuevapropiedad(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NuevaPropiedad(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            propiedad = PropiedadesCond(idUser=request.user, Condominio=request.session["idCondominio"], Numero=request.POST.get("Numero", ""), Nombre=request.POST.get("Nombre", ""), Tamanom2=request.POST.get("Tamanom2", ""), Ocupante=request.POST.get("Ocupante", ""), Propietario=request.POST.get("Propietario", ""), Telefono=request.POST.get("Telefono", ""), Celular=request.POST.get("Celular", ""), Correo=request.POST.get("Correo", ""))
            form.save()
            return render(request, "immovelc/propiedades.html")
        else:
            return render(request, "immovelc/nuevapropiedad.html",
                          {"form": form})
    return  render(request, "immovelc/nuevapropiedad.html")
```

forms.py

```
class NuevaPropiedad(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PropiedadesCond
        fields = ["Numero", "Nombre", "Tamanom2", "Ocupante", "Propietario", "Telefono", "Celular", "Correo"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using a `MOdelFOrm`, `propiedad = PropiedadesCond(idUser=request.user, ... ` is not needed.. YOu can just do `propiedad = form.save(commit=False)` and then `propiedad.save()`

Comment: I tried that but it gives the following error: IntegrityError at /nuevapropiedad/
ImmovelCondominios_propiedadescond.Condominio_id may not be NULL

Comment: Ok.. Do `propiedad.Condominio = request.session.` step before `form.save()`

Comment: I did it like this: propiedad = form.save(commit=False)
            propiedad.Condominio = request.session["idCondominio"]
            propiedad.save() However I'm getting the original error

Answer (score 0):

```
propiedad = 
    PropiedadesCond(
    idUser=request.user, 
    Condominio=request.session["idCondominio"],    # <------- problem
    Numero=request.POST.get("Numero", ""), Nombre=request.POST.get("Nombre", ""),
    Tamanom2=request.POST.get("Tamanom2", ""),
    Ocupante=request.POST.get("Ocupante", ""), 
    Propietario=request.POST.get("Propietario", ""), 
    Telefono=request.POST.get("Telefono", ""), 
    Celular=request.POST.get("Celular", ""), 
    Correo=request.POST.get("Correo", ""))
```

---

Without seeing your Propiedades Model, I would hazard a guess that you need to
get or instantiate the Condominio object first before constructing the Propiedades object.
The constructor will attempt to assign the unicode string u'1' that you get from the session to a Condominio object, which causes the error you describe.